# Is there any way I can restore previous version of Sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint online. I am wondering if any I edit in homepage of communication site and after few days I want previous view how can I restore it. I dont want it to do manually. Is there any way to restore previous version or view in Classic SharePoint site.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are referring to a page here, not a site.  You can turn on Versioning in your pages library so that when you edit a page it will save the changes as a new version, then you can go into the pages library and revert to a previous version.

If you are referring to a site restore, then you will have to open a support request with Microsoft, through the O365 admin center, to have the site restored from backup.  Fair warning that Microsoft only keeps a limited number of days worth of backups, and the restore process is not very quick......

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer. It helps. Can I ask You one more question, Where can I ecute scripts in SharePoint Site for changes in background images or any thing else?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SharePoint Stackexchange! If the provieded answer was helpful, please accept it. Create a new question for the second topic.

Comment: For executing PowerShell scripts against SharePoint Online you can run them from any PC.  I recommend looking into PowerShell PNP for managing SharePoint Online.  https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell

Comment: Thank you heaps.